# I want to apply margin on canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I want to move my canvas a little up: it should change from this:

[image: figure 1]

...to this:

[image: figure 2]

The w3Schools page on the [`rect`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_rect.asp) method is not really helping me out.

The canvas is created with `document.createElement('canvas')` which is how I want it.

Here is the code I am trying with:

```
Potree.TextSprite.prototype.update = function(){

    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.setAttribute("id", "canvas_Rect");
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.font = this.fontsize + "px " + this.fontface;

    //document.getElementById("#canvas_Rect").style.marginTop = "-50px";
    // get size data (height depends only on font size)
    var metrics = context.measureText( this.text );
    var textWidth = metrics.width;
    var margin = 5;
    var spriteWidth = 2*margin + textWidth + 2 * this.borderThickness;
    var spriteHeight = this.fontsize * 1.4 + 2 * this.borderThickness;

    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.canvas.width = spriteWidth;
    context.canvas.height = spriteHeight;

    context.font = this.fontsize + "px " + this.fontface;

    // background color
    context.fillStyle   = "rgba(" + this.backgroundColor.r + "," + this.backgroundColor.g + ","
                                  + this.backgroundColor.b + "," + this.backgroundColor.a + ")";
    // border color
    context.strokeStyle = "rgba(" + this.borderColor.r + "," + this.borderColor.g + ","
                                  + this.borderColor.b + "," + this.borderColor.a + ")";

    context.lineWidth = this.borderThickness;
    this.roundRect(context, this.borderThickness/2, this.borderThickness/2, 
        textWidth + this.borderThickness + 2*margin, this.fontsize * 1.4 + this.borderThickness, 6);                          

    // text color
    context.strokeStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0)";
    context.strokeText( this.text, this.borderThickness + margin, this.fontsize + this.borderThickness);

    context.fillStyle = "rgba(" + this.textColor.r + "," + this.textColor.g + ","
                                  + this.textColor.b + "," + this.textColor.a + ")";
    context.fillText( this.text, this.borderThickness + margin, this.fontsize + this.borderThickness);


    var texture = new THREE.Texture(canvas); 
    texture.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
    texture.magFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;
    texture.needsUpdate = true; 

    //var spriteMaterial = new THREE.SpriteMaterial( 
    //  { map: texture, useScreenCoordinates: false } );
    this.sprite.material.map = texture;

    this.sprite.scale.set(spriteWidth*0.01,spriteHeight*0.01,1.0);

    //this.material = spriteMaterial;                         
};

Potree.TextSprite.prototype.roundRect = function(ctx, x, y, w, h, r) {
    //  document.getElementById("#canvas_Rect").style.marginTop = "-50px";
    console.log(ctx)
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x+r, y);
    ctx.lineTo(x+w-r, y);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x+w, y, x+w, y+r);
    ctx.lineTo(x+w, y+h-r);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x+w, y+h, x+w-r, y+h);
    ctx.lineTo(x+r, y+h);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y+h, x, y+h-r);
    ctx.lineTo(x, y+r);
    ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x, y, x+r, y);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.stroke();   
};
```

I'm trying to apply a margin to it. How can I make it work?

Comment: Please post your code instead of a link. Only include the relevant bits.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want this canvas to be in the flow of the document or if you're just looking for an easy way to position it.

But an easy way to position canvas is to add absolute positioning to it..

*canvasID*.style.position = 'absolute';

Now just position the top, left, etc to whatever you need..

*canvasID*.style.top/left/etc = ??px;

Comment: If i am setting the id with canvas.setAttribute(id,...); and apply some style than it is also giving me an error which is " unable to apply style on null object"